# .NET Exception. Application code to blame, or .NET itself?

Tags: .net

I'm not a .NET developer, but we have a company who developed an application with .NET that is constantly crashing. In the event log, we see many crash dumps. Below is one of them. Basically, the developer is saying that it is a .NET issue and not their code, but from what I know about coding, the exception is saying that they are not handling an exception correctly. I don't know enough to refute them. Can anyone offer insight as to what the issue might (really) be (I don't trust the developer, as their product has been horrendous throughout the process), or what parts of the message might indicate that it is an issue that the developer needs to deal with, and not Microsoft (or, if the error dictates, the reverse)? Thanks in advance.

```
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException
Stack:
at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.ConstructName(System.RuntimeTypeHandle,
System.TypeNameFormatFlags,
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.StringHandleOnStack)
at System.RuntimeType+RuntimeTypeCache.ConstructName(System.String ByRef,
System.TypeNameFormatFlags) at
System.RuntimeType+RuntimeTypeCache.GetName(System.TypeNameKind)
at System.RuntimeType.get_FullName()
at System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.ToString(TraceFormat)
at System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.ToString()
at
System.Runtime.Diagnostics.DiagnosticTraceBase.StackTraceString(System.Excep
tion)
at
System.Runtime.Diagnostics.EtwDiagnosticTrace.WriteExceptionToTraceString(Sy
stem.Xml.XmlTextWriter, System.Exception, Int32, Int32) at
System.Runtime.Diagnostics.EtwDiagnosticTrace.ExceptionToTraceString(System.
Exception, Int32) at
System.Runtime.Diagnostics.EtwDiagnosticTrace.GetSerializedPayload(System.Ob
ject, System.Runtime.Diagnostics.TraceRecord, System.Exception, Boolean) at
System.Runtime.TraceCore.ThrowingEtwException(System.Runtime.Diagnostics.Etw
DiagnosticTrace, System.String, System.String, System.Exception) at
System.Runtime.ExceptionTrace.TraceEtwException(System.Exception,
System.Diagnostics.TraceEventType)
at
System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ExceptionUtility.ThrowHelper(System.Exceptio
n, System.Diagnostics.TraceEventType,
System.Runtime.Diagnostics.TraceRecord)
at
System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnectionInitiator.Connect(System.Uri,
System.TimeSpan) at
System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedConnectionInitiator.Connect(System.Uri,
System.TimeSpan) at
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper.EstablishConnection(System
.TimeSpan)
at
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(System
.TimeSpan)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(System.TimeSpan)
at
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableChannelBinder`1+ChannelSynchronizer+Syn
cWaiter[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].TryGetChannel()
at
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableChannelBinder`1+ChannelSynchronizer+Syn
cWaiter[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].TryWait(System.__Canon ByRef) at
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableChannelBinder`1+ChannelSynchronizer[[Sy
stem.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].TryGetChannel(Boolean, Boolean,
System.TimeSpan, System.ServiceModel.Channels.MaskingMode, System.__Canon
ByRef) at
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableChannelBinder`1[[System.__Canon,
mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Send(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message,
System.TimeSpan, System.ServiceModel.Channels.MaskingMode)
at
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableOutputSessionChannelOverDuplex.OnConnec
tionSend(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message, System.TimeSpan, Boolean,
Boolean) at
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableOutputSessionChannel.OnConnectionSendHa
ndler(System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageAttemptInfo, System.TimeSpan,
Boolean) at
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableOutputConnection.InternalAddMessage(Sys
tem.ServiceModel.Channels.Message, System.TimeSpan, System.Object, Boolean)
at
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableOutputSessionChannel.OnSend(System.Serv
iceModel.Channels.Message, System.TimeSpan) at
System.ServiceModel.Channels.OutputChannel.Send(System.ServiceModel.Channels
.Message, System.TimeSpan) at
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OutputChannelBinder.Send(System.ServiceModel.
Channels.Message, System.TimeSpan) at
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(System.String, Boolean,
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ProxyOperationRuntime, System.Object[],
System.Object[], System.TimeSpan) at
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(System.Runtim
e.Remoting.Messaging.IMethodCallMessage,
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ProxyOperationRuntime)
at
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(System.Runtime.Remot
ing.Messaging.IMessage)
at
System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(System.Runtime.Remot
ing.Proxies.MessageData ByRef, Int32) at
Nvents.Services.Wcf.IEventService.Publish(System.Object)
```

Comment: Errors are ALWAYS programmer error (99.99% of the time)

Comment: Since it is .NET internal code that is crashing here it is not the fault of the library author. Generating a StackTrace should not crash. But your machine might be hosed or something.

Comment: It could be compiled in the wrong version for the PC. IE x86 or x64

Comment: No, the problem is not .NET, but there is something very strange.  It appears to be that when a WCF connection is attempting to be made, an exception is being thrown.  During the low-level ETW logging, a different exception is occurring.  It may be that your system is not configured correctly for ETW logging, or it may be that your ETW provider has issues, is corrupt, or your machine is just generally in a bad state.  Does the problem occur on more than one system?  This can also happen if the developer is using ETW logging but has not correctly versioned his ETW manifest.

Comment: Hi guys, Thanks for the input. We have this happening on 20+ different machines, at different times, with slightly different errors each time. This is just one of the errors, if that helps.

Comment: @Ryan, if you can run it on a "clean" computer that has never had the software installed on it, you can isolate the problem to an ETW manifest update issue if the software works correctly.

Comment: Whether or not it's the framework that is the actual culprit should be a moot point. Part of writing code is dealing with situations where the specs of the framework doesn't actually match reality. Or are they claiming their program doesn't need to work as long as they produce syntactically correct code? This isn't so much a programming question as it is a legal question.

Comment: @Erik, thanks. I'll fire up a clean VM to test.

Comment: @JonC, thanks for the input. While I whole-heartedly agree, these guys have finger-pointed at every step they could. "It's the network. It's your server. It's the database." Etc. and we've proven them incorrect at each turn, but with code I'm unfamiliar with I simply don't know enough to refute them. But going to MSFT with this because they "say" that it is .NET's fault is just asinine and a waste of time, if they are truly continuing to blow smoke, that is.

Comment: do you see in the log adjacent errors/warnings related to this one you posted?

Comment: I would look in the section of code referencing InteropServices, as the top line appears to be complaining about a method "ConstructName," which may be a poorly implemented dll import.